# Is there a way in css to set values depending on an images size in css?

Tags: css, image

**Is there a way in css to set `float:left;` on an image when an image is like 30% but `float:none;` when an image is like 90% ?**

e.g.

```
<=30%:
    img {
        float:left;
    }

>=90%:
    img {
        float:none;
    }
```

*I'm doing something like this now:*

```
img {
    max-width:90%;
    float:left;
}

.page2 img {
    max-width:70%;
}
```

*What am I trying to achieve?* In my CMS users add images and texts.  If a user adds an image that is about 90% of the width and I have float:left then a very small portion of text is shown to right of the image. My solution today is to set max-width:70% on the image so a large portion of the image is shown (so it looks better). The issue is that I never know how large images users add to the CMS.

The ultimate solution would be if it was possible to set float-value depending on what size (width) of the image that is inserted. Think media-queries with percentages (from parent) for a specific element :-) I don't think this is possible but someone may have a workaround?

Please tell me if my problem is not explained well.

Answer (score 1):

A plausible solution is to have 2 separate CSS classes and

```
.imageSizeLessThan30 {
float: left;
}
.imageSizeMoreThan30 {
float: none;
}
```

Now install the below npm package:

[npm package [classnames]](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Just go through it once it's understandable, depending on the condition you can set classname variable as .imageSizeLessThan30 or .imageSizeMoreThan30, assign this result to a variable and use that variable inside the image tag as classname.

Comment: This is maybe a plausible solution but it's not css :-) In Js it would be easy enough to do without installing other thirdparty stuff.